# Designing webpage for iphone, can you change the html?

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile

I'm linking to an alternate .css for the iphone, but is it possible to link to an alternate .html? I'm not overly keen on going through the original html, although I will if I have to.

Thanks for any help,

Tom

Comment: you can check per javascript in the onload event if the user is using a mobile browser. If yes you can redirect to a mobile page.

Comment: best way just use `media query` then you don't have you redirect or second option is use of `javascript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this [detect handheld device in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery)  you will be able to know what kind of handheld is loading your page and than you may redirect the user to your new html page.
Something like:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )
{
    location.href = "new-page.html";
}
```